# Replace the default templates that Grails generates

Tags: grails

So, i am getting started with Grails and i just started using `install-templates`! And it is a pretty cool stuff.

I learned that i should modify the installed templates before using `generate-all`, `generate-views` or `generate-controllers`.

But what i couldn't figure out (and also i couldn't find in google) is how to make the changes i have made to the template permanent. A want to make the changes i have made to be used for all the projects i create from now on.

In a nutshell, How can i change the default templates Grails generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the scaffolding-X.X.X.zip at grails-X-X-X\plugins (the place you installed it) so the generate goes for all the projects.

Comment: That doesn't help very much at all. That just changes your local plugin zip so your templates are customized, but it has no effect for other developers

Comment: It answer the question. There's no other way to override the default scaff without modifying it directly on the scaffold plugin source.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `src/templates/scaffolding` and edit the files.

Comment: Really, and that would make it to **all other projects**?